# Get corresponding Range for Button interface object

Tags: vba, excel, button

I want when I click the button "Sélectionner un poste" it will tell me the position. (The button which I clicked in which row.)

Code to create the button:

```vb
Sub AjouterBoutonPoste(positionX As Integer, positionY As Integer, nom As String)
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(positionX, positionY), Cells(positionX, positionY))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "PosteBtAction"
        .Caption = "Sélectionner un poste"
        .Name = nom & CStr(positionX) & CStr(positionY)
    End With
End Sub
```

Code for the event button:

```vb
Sub PosteBtAction()
   AssocierSessoinCandidature.Show
End Sub
```

I have an application window named `AssocierSessoinCandidature`. I want the position which I clicked sent to the application window.

Here is my example Excel sheet:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the below Sub when the button is clicked

```
Sub foo()

Dim obj As Object
Dim row_no As Integer

Set obj = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
With obj.TopLeftCell
    row_no = .Row
End With
MsgBox "The Button is in the row number " & row_no

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties of the `Button` object for `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` to get the range addresses that bound the control:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn As Object
    Dim strAddressTopLeft As String
    Dim strAddressBottomRight As String
    Dim strButtonName As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each btn In ws.Buttons
        strAddressTopLeft = btn.TopLeftCell.Address
        strAddressBottomRight = btn.BottomRightCell.Address
        strButtonName = btn.Name
        Debug.Print "Range of button (" & strButtonName & "): " & _
            strAddressTopLeft & ":" & _
            strAddressBottomRight
    Next btn

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something very similar, you can adapt the below code:

```
Sub Button24_Click()
Dim strShape As String
strShape = Shapes("button24").TopLeftCell.Address
CallAnotherFunction strShape
End Sub
```

Upon clicking the button, this code will take the range of button24 as a string (not sure why I didn't use a range, you could if you wish) and pass it to the function `CallAnotherFunction`

In summary, this is what you need:

```
Shapes("button24").TopLeftCell.Address
```

or

```
Shapes("button24").TopLeftCell.Row
```