# Button Loses Functionality When Moved

Tags: excel, vba

I created a button using Excel VBA.

```vb
'Set dltBtn equal to t's position and size.
Set dltBtn = activeSheet.Buttons.Add(u.Left, u.Top, u.Width, u.Height)

'Start of With.
With dltBtn
    
    'Macro that is called when dltBtn is clicked.
    .OnAction = "'ESQDeleteRecord " & u.Column & "," & u.Row & "'"
    'Caption of dltBtn, shown to the user.
    .Caption = "Delete ESQ Record"
    'Name of dltBtn, used by Excel.
    .Name = "ESQ Delete Button"
    
'End of With.
End With
```

This code creates a button at the desired location with the correct size. It functions correctly, as clicking the Delete Button will activate the following macro:

```vb
'Sub to process when a record is chosen for deletion.
Sub ESQDeleteRecord(ByVal colPos As Integer, rowPos As Integer)

'MsgBox "I respond to clicking."

'Declares a Checkbox named cb.
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim deleteRange As Range
Dim msgRes As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim count As Integer

'Start of for loop which will run from count up to 17.
For count = 1 To 17
    On Error Resume Next

    'Start of if statement which says if the cell's value two cells to the left and up until it hits a non-blank cell of the Target cell is equal to ESQ.
    If Cells(rowPos - count, colPos + 1).Value = "ESQ" Then

        'If Cells(rowPos - count, colPos + 1).Value <> "Legacy" Then

            'Set deleteRange = Range(Cells(rowPos, colPos + 1), Cells(rowPos - 17, colPos + 1))

            msgRes = MsgBox("Proceed to delete ESQ Record?", vbOKCancel, "ESQ Record Delete")

            If msgRes = vbOK Then

                Set deleteRange = Range(Cells(rowPos, colPos + 1), Cells(rowPos - 17, colPos + 1))

                For Each cb In activeSheet.CheckBoxes

                    If Not Intersect(cb.TopLeftCell, deleteRange) Is Nothing Then

                        cb.Delete

                    End If

                Next cb

            End If

            deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

            Exit For

        'End If

    End If

Next count

End Sub
```

These two macros combined are used to delete records that have been input into a table. When a record is entered, the delete button to delete that particular record is created alongside it.

The problem arises when there are multiple records within a single sheet. Deleting a record causes all of the below records to shift up. When any other delete button is clicked after this, nothing happens.

I believe the moving of the delete button from its original place is what is causing this to happen.

Is there is a way to tie a macro to a button so that it activates regardless of whether the button has moved? That would be the ideal solution but if it is not possible I will go another route with this deletion.

As I understand it, the macro is not "linked" to the cell where it is positioned, it's merely placed there at the same size as the cell beneath it. Am I understanding this correctly?

Edit: Found an answer thanks to @Rory. He provided me with `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell`, which led me to [Excel VBA - Get corresponding Range for Button interface object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222992/excel-vba-get-corresponding-range-for-button-interface-object)

I accepted a different answer as a solution for this question to be answered, as I did not know how to accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: this is exactly why you shouldn't use `Cells` without `wb`/`ws`

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next` by the way, it's just hiding potential errors.

Comment: You could use `Activesheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Topleftcell` to get a reference to the cell under the top left corner of the clicked button. That way you don't have to worry about passing arguments with `Onaction` (which is best avoided) or about buttons moving up or down rows but their macros still referring to the old row number.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: @Rory I should place that line in the delete record button macro then?

Comment: You use that to determine which row and column you are interested in (you can simply access the Row and Column properties of that range). Then you can simply assign that macro, without arguments, to all the buttons.

Comment: @Rory Thanks for your input. Using the line of code you gave me, I searched online and found this answer which worked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222992/excel-vba-get-corresponding-range-for-button-interface-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of use case a hyperlink would be much more useful/robust - it's actually contained within the row, so will always move along with the rest of the data, and you can reliably use its location to determine which row needs to be acted on.

Add a "delete" link - for example:

```
Sub Setup()
    Dim u As Range
    For Each u In Range("B2:B10")
        u.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add u, _
             Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & u.Parent.Name & "'!" & u.Address(False, False), _
             TextToDisplay:="Delete"
    Next u
End Sub
```

In the worksheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim rng As Range
    Select Case Target.TextToDisplay
        Case "Delete"
            Set rng = Target.Range.Offset(1)
            Target.Range.EntireRow.Delete
            rng.Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'll have to get back to you tomorrow on whether this solution works. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found an answer another way, but accepted yours as an answer to close the question. Thanks again.