# Reset cell back to formula after Drop Down override

Tags: excel

I have a workflow in which a cell has a formula in it that uses xlookup to find a value. A user can use a drop down through data validation to change that value to something else. I am looking for a way to reset the cell back to the xlookup formula that is not VBA labor intensive. I have 125 records that I would want to toggle the ability for separately but I don't want to write 125 different macros.

Comment: If you have 125 different rows, that does not necessarily mean that you need 125 different macros, if the row use the same Xlookup function, but that is assuming the formula follows the same logic in all rows. You need to elaborate if it doesn't.

Comment: Basically, you have a cell with a drop-down and a default value. The default value is derived from a formula and not included in the drop-down list. However, you want it back under some circumstances. The best answer would be to have it included in the list which means that you need code to create a different one for each row, with the XLOOKUP integrated into the code. The alternative is to add the XLOOKUP into the cell using code. Either way you need the lookup function in the code. Therefore it must be in your question. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a tough nut to crack. Good spreadsheet design practice is to have cells dedicated to EITHER formula OR manual input. You're combining bad spreadsheet design with a desire not to use VBA to fix what gets destroyed by the bad design. Well, you can't eat your cake and still have it in your hand.

Consider using a completely separate column for the drop-down, so the formula does NOT get destroyed when a drop-down value is selected.

Comment: Understand it is not ideal design but it is the requirements that were given to me. Just wondering if there is a better way than writing a bunch of VBA.

Comment: to get the formula back, it needs to be entered into the cell again. To do that, you will have to remove the data validation, because it will not allow the formula as a valid entry. And in order to speed this process up, you will need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222992/excel-vba-get-corresponding-range-for-button-interface-object) to simplify the code. I will still need multiple buttons but the code is very simple.

Comment: How does that answer relate to your question? You never posted the formula that you need to repair after it was overwritten. You may not need multiple buttons. There may be solutions that are much simpler. But we cannot tell unless you post your formula.